# How to make UIImageView.clipsToBounds = NO allow userInteraction outside of bounds?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I currently have my `UIImageView.clipsToBounds = NO;` and it works great except I need `userInteraction` to be enabled so that if a child view is touched I can respond to the touch. Anyone know how to keep `UIImageView.clipsToBounds = NO;` but still allow user interaction outside of the bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement UIGestureRecognizerDelegate's method.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if (touch.view != YourImageView) { // accept only touchs on superview, not accept touchs on subviews
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with using implementing delegates but I put that code at the top of my .m file and it didn't work. Am I implementing it wrong? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: use@interface YourFilename <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> in your .h file then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the `UIImageView` User interaction default `UIImageView` userInteration shall be disabled.

```
yourImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle the action of tap on the clipped bounds of the `UIImageView`. Implement the `tochesBegan:withEvent:` on UIImageView's superview class. Check whether the touch location is inside the bounds of the imageView's bounds then you have tapped the location. For achieving this do the following:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint point = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.imageView];
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(self.imageView.bounds, point)) {
        // Your code on tap of UIImgeView.
        NSLog(@"image view is tapped");
    }
}
```

This may help you.